# Use subdomain as route parameter in Meteor.js

Tags: node.js, routes, meteor, subdomain, url-routing

I want to create a meteor.js app that uses subdomain as a url parameter. It will be username, so if user types: myusername.theapp.com app will show theapp.com customized with data and/or login for user myusername.

How can I do this? Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client-side its easy, you can use `window.location.hostname` in router or somewhere else and parse it to get your username. You can also use it as a variable in subscriptions etc. and pass it to server.

Just remember that changing hostname will require full page reload, so it wont be very user-friendly.

Comment: And is there a way to do it server side? Or this is the best way?

Comment: @DavidCollado you don't want to do it server side :) Remember that you have many "client side apps" running at the same time, but all of them are connecting to one node.js instance on your server, and that server app should be hostname-agnostic :) You best way IMHO is by passing hostname in calls/subscriptions and returning data accordingly.

Comment: and is there a way to prevent a user changes that and gets other domain info? Is it possible to check out of client that this user + domain is ok?